# What is it meant by "sanctions grip"?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

What is it meant by "sanctions grip" in the following sentence:

"China, Germany defend Iran business ties as U.S. sanctions grip"?

Is *sanctions* here a plural noun or singular verb?

That sentence was the title of a Netscape [news article](https://isp.netscape.com/politics/story/0002/20180808/KBN1KT1B8_3) (which is not available in the EU).

Can anyone explain it please?

Comment: Look up the verb *grip* in good dictionary. Good Luck.

Comment: @Kris The US could have approved (or condemned) a grip. Either word could be the verb.

Comment: In the (figurative) grip of sanctions.

Comment: It's all metaphor, but I would just point out that [*as sanctions **grip***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+sanctions+grip%22) has only 38 hits in Google Books, making it a relatively "unusual" choice compared to [*as sanctions **bite***,](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+sanctions+bite%22.) with over 1000 hits. And I don't think there's any possibility that the writer intended some subtle nuance by his choice (which could also have been *as sanctions **take hold**,* to use another "physical attack" metaphor).

Answer (score 1):

In the sentence "China, Germany defend Iran business ties as U.S. sanctions grip",

[sanctions](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sanction?q=sanctions) is indeed a plural noun and [grip](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grip) is the verb.

> Sanction[ C usually plural ] an official order, such as the stopping of trade, that is taken against a country in order to make it obey international law

and

> grip (of an emotion or situation) have a strong or adverse effect on.

The first six paragraphs in the article state:

> **China and Germany defended their business ties with Iran** on Wednesday **in the face of President Donald Trump’s warning that any companies trading with the Islamic Republic would be barred from the United States**.
>
> **The comments** from Beijing **signalled growing anger from partners of the United States**, which reimposed strict sanctions against Iran on Tuesday, **over its threat to penalize businesses from third countries that continue to operate there**.
>
> “China has consistently opposed unilateral sanctions and long-armed jurisdiction,” the Chinese foreign ministry said.
>
> “China’s commercial cooperation with Iran is open and transparent, reasonable, fair and lawful, not violating any United Nations Security Council resolutions,” it added in a faxed statement to Reuters.
>
> “**China’s lawful rights should be protected**.”
>
> **The German government said** U.S. **sanctions** against Iran **that have an extra-territorial effect violate international law**, and **Germany *expects Washington to consider European interests* when coming up with such sanctions.**

The meaning of who is impacted is explained further in the article in the following paragraphs:

> Trump tweeted on Tuesday: “These are the most biting sanctions ever imposed, and in November they ratchet up to yet another level. Anyone doing business with Iran will NOT be doing business with the United States.”
>
> EUROPEANS WITHDRAW
>
> *European countries, hoping to persuade Tehran to continue to
>   respect the deal, have promised to try to lessen the blow of 
>   sanctions and to urge their firms not to pull out. But that has
>   proved difficult:*
>
> **European companies have quit Iran, arguing
>   that they cannot risk their U.S. business**.
>       Among those that have suspended plans to invest in Iran are
>   France's oil major Total          , its big carmakers PSA
>             and Renault          , and their German rival Daimler
>             .
>       Danish engineering company Haldor Topsoe, one of the world's
>   leading industrial catalyst producers, said on Wednesday it
>   would cut around 200 jobs from its workforce of 2,700 due to the
>   new U.S sanctions on Iran, which made it very hard for its
>   customers there to finance new projects.
>       The chief executive of reinsurance group Munich Re
>              said it may abandon its Iran business under pressure
>   from the United States, but described the operation as very
>   small.

In other words, the Chinese and German governments have defended their continued business dealings with Iran but at the same time are concerned because some companies are withdrawing from doing business in Iran as this can potentially affect their interests in the U.S.

Comment: So instead of that we can say : China, Germany defend Iran business ties as U.S. sanctions grip European companies !!!

Comment: @Mahmoud_2003, yes from what I understood that's what the article is saying. The first six paragraphs of the article refer to the Chinese and German government's position on U.S. sanctions against Iran.

Comment: thanks a lot ... Can you tell me how I can  contact you if you don't mind ?

Comment: @Mahmoud_2003 That is not an appropriate question here; if users allow contact then you can look in their [personal profiles](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/309120/bookmanu?tab=profile) for details. When you have 20 rep you can join [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-and-usage).

Comment: @Andrew Leach♦ what is 20 rep???

Comment: @Mahmoud_2003 20 [reputation points](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). Points bring [privileges](https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges). Do have a look round the help pages.

Comment: @Mahmoud_2003 I've created a chat room entitled "What is it meant by “sanctions grip”?". https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81400/what-is-it-meant-by-sanctions-grip You can join me there after you achieve the 20 rep privilege.

Answer (score 0):

[Grip](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/grip) is a verb here meaning:

> - If something grips you, it affects you very strongly.

(Collins)

Commercial sanctions imposed by the U.S.A are beginning to show their effects.

Comment: But here, who is gripped by sanctions ? I think grip (here) is an intransitive verb because object isn't mentioned

Comment: @Mahmoud_2003 - I can't access your link, It is not visible in Europe for some reason. I guess it refers to sanctions imposed on Iran. https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2018/aug/08/donald-trump-sanctions-iran-international-law

Comment: Here is another link of the article : https://abomus.de/en/news/usa-populyarnoe/379336-china-germany-defend-iran-business-ties-us-sanctions-grip

Comment: @Mahmoud_2003 - yes, it refers to sanctions against Iran: *"Tuesday’s sanctions target Iran’s purchases of U.S. dollars, metals trading, coal, industrial software and the auto sector.

Trump tweeted on Tuesday: “These are the most biting sanctions ever imposed, and in November they ratchet up to yet another level. Anyone doing business with Iran will NOT be doing business with the United States.”*

Comment: Grip (here) .. Is it a transitive or intransitive verb ?!! And if it's transitive where is the object ???

Comment: @Mahmoud_2003, After all, it's a headline and needn't be a complete sentence with the SVO structure. The object is implied and so elided.